# Extract only year from complete date in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my json data structure:

```
[
   [
    {
     "nos": 0,
     "name": "A S MUSIC AND DANCE A CULTURAL ORGANIZATION",
     "unique_id": "AN/2020/0259067",
      "reg_details": [
                       {
                        "registered_with": "Registrar of Societies"
                        },
                        {
                        "type_of_ngo": "Registered Societies (Non-Government)"
                         },
                            {
                            "registration_no": "1534"
                              },
                           {
                              "copy_of_registration_certificate": "Available"
                           },
                            {
                              "copy_of_pan_card": "Available"
                             },                    
                              {
                               "date_of_registration": "25-05-2016"
                              }
],
```

I just want to compare with the **Year** only from date key,value i.e `"date_of_registration": "25-05-2016"`.

My Button which is taking values from the widgets is:

```
    RoundedButton(
                      text: "Next",
                      press: () async {
                        debugPrint(_currentValue.toString());
                        _NgoDetail(ngo,_currentValue.toString());
                       //Where _currentValue is actually the year I'm getting 
                        //from a spinner widget

                      },
                    ),
```

And the function that is performing comparison with these values is:

```
  Future<bool>  _NgoDetail(String name,String year) async { //Only Year as a 
                                                //  parameter and not whole date
    String jsonString = await _loadANgoAsset();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    int k=-2;
   
    List<dynamic> allNamesOfNGO=jsonResponse[0];


    allNamesOfNGO.takeWhile((value) => value != name).forEach((allNamesOfNGO){
      (allNamesOfNGO as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((key, value) {
       ++k;
        if(key=='name' && value == name){
           if(key=='date_of_registeration' && value == year) //Here value is 
                                                          //complete date, I want 
                                                          //it to be year only
           {
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> R3(jsonIndexOfNGO:k)));
           }                          
        }
        else{
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Your given details doesn't match. Please try again",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0);
        }

      } );
    });

  



  }
```

What should I do in above function first? Retrive all date values from the json and convert their formate from this `25-02-2015` to `2015` or perform some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    List<dynamic> allNamesOfNGO=jsonResponse[0];


    allNamesOfNGO.takeWhile((value) => value != name).forEach((allNamesOfNGO){
      (allNamesOfNGO as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((key, value) {
       ++k;
        if(key=='name' && value == name){
           if(key=='date_of_registeration' && value.substring(6) == year) //Here value is 
                                                          //complete date, I want 
                                                          //it to be year only
           {
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> R3(jsonIndexOfNGO:k)));
           }                          
        }
        else{
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Your given details doesn't match. Please try again",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0);
        }

      }
```

Comment: Argument is already in year format. I mean its 2015 or 2016 etc. I want to extract and compare value from API in such a way that it is only year and not 25-02-2015 in the function `_NgoDetail(String name, String Year)`. Please edit your answer again. Thanks!